# Adding system calls to print all disk blocks occupied by the file

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, inode, ext4

How can we print all disk blocks occupied by a file by adding a system call?

My Linux version is 4.2.6 and my File system is ext4.

Which  Linux C library could be helpful?

Comment: dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894824/linux-how-do-i-know-the-block-map-of-the-given-file-and-or-the-free-space-map

Comment: How do you know a file occupies any disk blocks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux - How do i know the block map of the given file and/or the free space map of the partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894824/linux-how-do-i-know-the-block-map-of-the-given-file-and-or-the-free-space-map)