# How do I find the sector(s) a file is occupying in windows C?

Tags: c

I have tried Google'ing but I am finding nothing useful. There are many ways that I don't need(e.g. some linux command). I want to know how to find what hard drive sectors occupy a file **in windows C**.

NTFS and ext4

Comment: If there *is* a linux command then you might possibly call this one from within your C function (creating a `pipe`, `fork`ing, replace stdin/out_fileno with pipe ends, call that command via one of `exec` function family) – as a fallback, if you do not find the appropriate OS API for. Why would you want to interfere that low level with the OS at all? Might get a source of trouble...

Comment: For ext2-ext4 this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2894865/21105992 or possibly the FIBMAP answer on the same question. There is no generic way that would work for all filesystems (some may not even have blocks). Are you interested in a specific filesystem?

Comment: These linux commands just might be open source.

Comment: Something like [FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS IOCTL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_get_retrieval_pointers)?